# Show large string in a line which exceeds the page size (FPDF)

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to show the following array in a line without break.

```
$header = array('Sl.', 'Session.', 'Time','Filename','Operator Name','Mobile No.','Amount','SSL Status','SSL Time','Operator Status','Op.Time','Reversal Reqd.?');
```

But it exceeds the page size.

Please help me.

Comment: I've posted what I think is the solution, but when asking these kind of questions, next time please describe what you would like to achieve. If text won't fit, there are may options that you can choose, like shortening the text, increasing margin, decreasing font size, or introducing a new page. I figured you meant the last one, but I couldn't tell from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this extension to the FPDF class. It introduces the MultiCell method (for my convenience wrapped in the OutputLines method). In this method you can specify the maximum number of lines. Any part of the string that won't fit, will be returned from the function. In that case you can create a new function and call MultiCell again, until it returns `''`.

```
<?

require 'fpdf.php';
// Class voor implementate van handige aanvullende features.
class EPDF extends FPDF {

    function MultiCell($w, $h, $txt, $border=0, $align='J', $fill=false, $maxline=0)
    {
        //Output text with automatic or explicit line breaks, at most $maxline lines
        $cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
        if($w==0)
            $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
        $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
        $s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
        $nb=strlen($s);
        if($nb>0 && $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
            $nb--;
        $b=0;
        if($border)
        {
            if($border==1)
            {
                $border='LTRB';
                $b='LRT';
                $b2='LR';
            }
            else
            {
                $b2='';
                if(is_int(strpos($border,'L')))
                    $b2.='L';
                if(is_int(strpos($border,'R')))
                    $b2.='R';
                $b=is_int(strpos($border,'T')) ? $b2.'T' : $b2;
            }
        }
        $sep=-1;
        $shy=-1;
        $shy1=-1;
        $brk=-1;
        $lshy=0;
          $cx = '';
        $i=0;
        $j=0;
        $l=0;
        $ns=0;
        $nl=1;
        while($i<$nb)
        {
            //Get next character
            $c=$s[$i];
            if($c=="\n")
            {
                //Explicit line break
                if($this->ws>0)
                {
                    $this->ws=0;
                    $this->_out('0 Tw');
                }
                $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$i-$j),$b,2,$align,$fill);
                $i++;
                $sep=-1;
                $shy=-1;
                $shy1=-1;
                $brk=-1;
                $cx='';
                $j=$i;
                $l=0;
                $ns=0;
                $nl++;
                if($border && $nl==2)
                    $b=$b2;
                if($maxline && $nl>$maxline)
                    return substr($s,$i);
                continue;
            }
            if($c==' ')
            {
                $sep=$i;
                $ls=$l;
                $ns++;
            }
            // Soft break (&shy;)
            if ($c==$GLOBALS["hyphen"])
            {
                // Afbreektekentje. Onthouden van laatste en voorlaatste positie.
                $shy1=$shy;
                $shy=$i;
                $lshy1=$lshy;
                $lshy = $l;

                $l-=$cw[$c];
            }
            if ($c=='-')
            {
                $brk=$i;
                $ls = $l + $cw[$c];
                $ns++;
                $cy = '-';
            }
            $l+=$cw[$c];
            if($l>$wmax)
            {
                // Woord past niet meer. Kijken of het af te breken is op een hard afbreekstreepje
                if ($brk>$shy)
                {
                    if ($brk>$sep)
                    {
                        $sep=$brk;
                        $cx='-';
                    }
                }
                elseif ($shy > $sep) // Of op een soft afbreekstreepje
                {
                    if ($lshy + $cw['-'] > $wmax)
                    {
                        if ($shy1 > $sep)
                        {
                            $sep = $shy1;
                            $ls = $lshy1;
                            $cx = '-';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $sep = $shy;
                        $ls = $lshy;
                        $cx = '-';
                    }
                }

                //Automatic line break
                if($sep==-1)
                {
                    if($i==$j)
                        $i++;
                    if($this->ws>0)
                    {
                        $this->ws=0;
                        $this->_out('0 Tw');
                    }
                    $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$i-$j).$cx,$b,2,$align,$fill);
                }
                else
                {
                    if($align=='J')
                    {
                        $this->ws=($ns>1) ? ($wmax-$ls)/1000*$this->FontSize/($ns-1) : 0;
                        $this->_out(sprintf('%.3F Tw',$this->ws*$this->k));
                    }
                    $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$sep-$j).$cx,$b,2,$align,$fill);
                    $i=$sep+1;
                }
                $sep=-1;
                $shy=-1;
                $shy1=-1;
                    $cx = '';
                $j=$i;
                $l=0;
                $ns=0;
                $nl++;
                if($border && $nl==2)
                    $b=$b2;
                if($maxline && $nl>$maxline)
                {
                    if($this->ws>0)
                    {
                        $this->ws=0;
                        $this->_out('0 Tw');
                    }
                    return substr($s,$i);
                }
            }
            else
                $i++;
        }
        //Last chunk
        if($this->ws>0)
        {
            $this->ws=0;
            $this->_out('0 Tw');
        }
        if($border && is_int(strpos($border,'B')))
            $b.='B';
        $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$i-$j),$b,2,$align,$fill);
        $this->x=$this->lMargin;
        return '';
    }

    function OutputLines($w, $h, $text, $maxline = 0)
    {
        return $this->MultiCell($w, $h, $text, 0, 'L', false, $maxline);
    }

}
```